# Watson alchemy language API error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I trying to use Watson alchemy language. After registering on Bluemix and creating an instance I have got a "invalid-api-key" error on checking URL:

```
http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/info/GetAPIKeyInfo?apikey=<key>
```

The same error raised with using Python API.

Why is the new key not working?

Comment: So, what's not clear about the error message?

Comment: Why new key not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with ibm ticket system. it was a temporary bug in registration new key.